# Gif image not working in thymeleaf-html page?

Tags: html, image, gif, thymeleaf

in html image and gif are set as same way.  so i use same way in thymeleaf

In thymeleaf the image set as

```
 <img th:attr="src=@{${ball.png}} , title=#{background}, alt=#{background}" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
```

same as the gif image set as

```
<img th:attr="src=@{${run.gif}} , title=#{background}, alt=#{background}" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
```

the image will show there but gif image not shows there

i don't know why this happening.

if you know  the answer please share here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@{${run.gif}}` tries to URL rewrite with the property `gif` of an attribute `run`, which I doubt there is.

You should do `@{/run.gif}` if you want to refer to the image relatively to your context.

Documentation: [Thymeleaf URL Syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/standardurlsyntax.html)