# Loading .png images works but .gif doesn't in thymeleaf

Tags: html, image, thymeleaf, gif

I use this code to load png images and it always work:

```
<img src="cid:gamze.png" alt="mail-icon" width="110" height="110" border="0"/>
```

I want to load gif images the same way but it doesn't.

Here is the png and gift path ;
**project > src > resource > mail > img**

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

note : There is a link for this situation but 6 years ago.
[Gif image not working in thymeleaf-html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290665/gif-image-not-working-in-thymeleaf-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use both `.png` and `.gif` in my code using below line

```
<img  th:src="@{/image/2.gif}" alt="mail-icon" width="110" height="110" border="0"/>
```

Please inspect your generated html and verify the gif image is present at link as in `src` of `img`

Comment: I used **th:src="@{/img/gamze.gif}"**  and i get an error like this ;   "Link base \"/img/gamze.gif\" cannot be context relative (/) or page relative unless you implement the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (context is of class: org.thymeleaf.context.Context) ... "

Comment: Seems like you are using thymeleaf template to send images in email. In such case either refer http://forum.thymeleaf.org/No-Access-to-IWebContext-for-URL-in-th-href-td4027617.html OR try updating th:src="@{img/gamze.gif}" or th:src="@{mail/img/gamze.gif}" depending on the location of html w.r.t. image